# Is it possible to list consumer group members in Prometheus with Kafka Exporter?

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, strimzi

Kafka Exporter exposes the "kafka_consumergroup_members" metric which shows how many members there are in each consumer group. However, I was wondering if it is possible to list the actual members of each consumer group, similar to how using the "–group  –describe –members” options with the kafka-consumer-groups.sh shell script outputs the individual consumers of the specified group. Is it possible for this to be done with Kafka Exporter or any other Kafka related exporters?

Comment: You could add exporters to the consumers themselves, such as JMX exporter, assuming they are JVM based

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible with the Kafka Exporter. It focuses on consumer lag rather than the individual consumers. I'm also not sure it that would be a something what would fit well with Prometheus since it might generate a lot of active time series.

You can get such data for example using the Kafka Admin API from your own application (the Kafka Admin API is also used inside the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`).

Comment: I think using the Kafka Admin API is not applicable for my use case as I need to display the list of members on a Grafana Dashboard.

Comment: Well, Kafka Admin API gives you the data and once you have them I'm sure you can find some way to get it into Grafana if that is what you want.